# Different sizes of \Delta and \nabla

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

Math symbols `\Delta` and `\nabla` display different sizes in the following code within a text, `$\Delta P_1 \rightarrow  \nabla q_1 $` giving me the result shown on this pic

[image]

Any suggestion?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,aspectratio=43,compress,handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item Some text: $\Delta P_1 \rightarrow \nabla q_1 $
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: They are apparently from different fonts, but unless you post a *complete* example that can be compiled and run, nobody can guess how you might fix that.

Comment: The code does not generate the difference in size that you depicted (picture is completely different).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default sans serif math font in Beamer does not have a nabla symbol matching the delta. You can use serif math fonts to get similar symbols for `\Delta` and `\nabla`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,aspectratio=43,compress,handout]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item Some text: $\Delta P_1 \rightarrow \nabla q_1 $
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For my humble opinion you should to use `newtxmath` instead of the obsolete package `times`. Here there is a complete MWE without different sizes between `\Delta` and `\nabla`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,aspectratio=43,compress,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some text: $\Delta P_1 \rightarrow \nabla q_1 $
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```